# Trying to get image dimensions with Directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I have an endpoint that is returning an image url for me. I want to display in a component and have a label beneath the image to show the dimensions of the image.

I have written an attribute directive, GetDimensionsDirective, below to do this:

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, ElementRef, Renderer, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: "[get-dimensions]"
})

export class GetDimensionDirective {
    @Output() calculatedDimensions = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
        this.getDimensions();
    }
    getDimensions() {
        this.calculatedDimensions.emit({ "height": this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight, "width": this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth });
    }
}
```

And am consuming as so in my component:

```
<img get-dimensions (calculatedDimensions)="dimsGot(event)" [src]="image.url" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

and in my conponent I have the function:

```
import { GetDimensionDirective } from './../../../../shared/directives/get-dimesions';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-image',
  templateUrl: './image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image.component.css']
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
  image={url: "http://localhost/myApi.WebService/api/resource/12", dimensions:null};


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  dimsGot(dimensions) {
    this.image.dimensions = {};
  }
}
```

My "dimsGot" method in my component isn't being entered, can anyone advise why?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sussed it... I needed to bind to the "load" event of the element(img) thenperform my calculations and emi the result in EventEmitter like this in my directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, ElementRef, Renderer, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: "[get-dimensions]",
    host: {
        '(load)': 'getDimensions()'
      }    
})

export class GetDimensionDirective {
    @Output() calculatedDimensions = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }
    getDimensions() {
        this.calculatedDimensions.emit({ "height": this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight, "width": this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth });
    }
}
```

then when I hook into the directive in the markup wire into my method to handle the event like this:

```
<img get-dimensions (calculatedDimensions)="dimsGot($event)" [src]="image.url">
```

now in my component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-image',
  templateUrl: './image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image.component.css']
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
  image = { url: "myApi.WebService/api/resource/12", dimensions: { height: 0, width: 0 } };
.
.
.
.
      dimsGot(dims) {
        if (this.image && dims) {
          this.image.dimensions.height = dims.height;
          this.image.dimensions.width = dims.width;
        }
      }
```